# Read file ending early?

Tags: ruby

I ran into a weird thing where a line in a file is causing my Ruby script to finish reading the file early.

My code is:

```
File.readlines($file).each do |line|
    puts "line is: "+line.to_s
    line.each_byte do |c|
        if(c == 9 || c==10 || c==13 || (c>31 && c < 127))
            print c.chr
        end
    end
end
```

The file that I'm using has this single character that, in Notepad++ and Sublime Text 2, shows up as "SUB".

In the following line, it appears in between the `cr` and the `me` towards the end of the first line:

```
"ProductToken","estee-lauder-re-nutriv-replenishing-comfort-eye-crme-15ml"
"ProductToken","estee-lauder-youth-dew-body-satinee-150ml"
```

I have those same lines [in my dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gopikutl4s5i0gb/seo_urls_sample.csv).

When I execute that sample script above, it hits that character and then finishes. I suspect that it is the File method that is treating that character as an end of file.

The problem is that I've got absolutely no idea how to sort this out. I can do a find and replace in Sublime, or presumably using sed or something, but I'd prefer to not have to do that each time.

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3 on Windows.

Can I use file encoding or something? I have no idea what a file encoding is, let alone how to handle this.

Also, the original readline function was to take the contents of that CSV file, parse it, and then stick it into a hash.
The original file size is approximately 28mb, with over 350k unique lines from a database, so when I checked the size of the hash and found that it was only 2100 long, that led me to start looking into this.

---

As requested, I ran it through `od -c` on my Mac, and got the following:

```
0000000    "   P   r   o   d   u   c   t   T   o   k   e   n   "   ,   "  
0000020    e   s   t   e   e   -   l   a   u   d   e   r   -   r   e   -  
0000040    n   u   t   r   i   v   -   r   e   p   l   e   n   i   s   h  
0000060    i   n   g   -   c   o   m   f   o   r   t   -   e   y   e   -  
0000100    c   r 032   m   e   -   1   5   m   l   "  \n   "   P   r   o  
0000120    d   u   c   t   T   o   k   e   n   "   ,   "   e   s   t   e  
0000140    e   -   l   a   u   d   e   r   -   y   o   u   t   h   -   d  
0000160    e   w   -   b   o   d   y   -   s   a   t   i   n   e   e   -  
0000200    1   5   0   m   l   "  \n                                      
0000207
```

---

http://blob.perl.org/books/beginning-perl/3145_AppF.pdf

According to this, in octal, 032 is actually a SUB character.
In which case, if it is a valid ASCII character, why would Ruby think it is an end-of-file?

Comment: Do you have [CoreUtils](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) installed? Then you could use `od -c`to figure out what character it is. However it might be a `Ctrl-Z` which is the Windows End-of-file character, then the tool might skip on the character too and finish reading the file as your script does. Which program showed you the contents of your file in the way you presented it?

Comment: I'm using Sublime Text2 and Notepad++, both of which showed it as "SUB". Strangely, when I look at it in git bash via sed (which is how I extracted just those two lines as an example), it appears as an arrow pointing right, which I tend to associate with the tab character... Screenshot here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/q06ltatspnmd8g0/git-bash-and-sublime.png   First is from git bash, second is from sublime text.

Comment: Patru is correct. This is a Windows issue, because ASCII 032 is Ctrl-Z which indicates end-of-file on Windows. Testing on my Linux box, Ruby reads the whole file just fine.

Comment: Hey Max, based on your comment, I opened the file with encoding set to iso-8859-1 (UTF-8 apparently), hoping to bypass the windows encoding... And that worked! It seems to just strip out that character.

Comment: Hm... it shouldn't strip it out. My system shows it as `\u001A` when reading as unicode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bypass this issue by using `File#read`, which lets you specify the correct number of bytes to read.

```
File.open($file) do |f|
  f.read(f.size).each_line do |line|
    # ...
  end
end
```

Or even better, since your data are CSV, you can use the `csv` lib which also reads past the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>

```
require 'csv'
rows = CSV.read($file)
```

Comment: Reading it with the `t` option ([text file mode](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-c-new-label-IO+Open+Mode)) also seems to read past it, i.e., `File.open('file.csv', 'rt') { |file| file.each_line ... }`. I don't know what else "text file mode" changes though.

Comment: That is probably a good solution, though the whole data smells fishy if something which probably used to be "crème" turns into a control character like `Ctrl-Z` which is entirely unprintable on any operating system.

Comment: I also tried it this way (when I came back and saw that you'd provided an answer), and it is humming away happily, so I'm going to accept this as the answer too. Thanks!   @Patru: agreed. I want to go and find out what's happening with the character encodings...