# Parsing Text File in Ruby with "^z" Characters

Tags: ruby, io

I have a group of large text files with a ton of information in them with inconsistent formatting. I don't really care all that much about most of the info, but I'm trying to extract IDs that are included in the file. I've drafted a fairly simple script to do this (IDs are 3 digits - 7 digits).

```
puts("What's the name of the file you'd like to check? (don't include .txt)")

file_to_check = gets.chomp
file_to_write = file_to_check + "IDs" + ".txt"
file_to_check = file_to_check + ".txt"
output_text = ""
count_of_lines = 0

File.open(file_to_check, "r").each_line do |line|
    count_of_lines += 1
    if /.*\d{3}-\d{7}.*/ =~ line
        temp_case = line.match(/\d{3}-\d{7}/).to_s
        temp_case = temp_case + "\n"
        output_text = output_text + temp_case
    else
        # puts("this failed")
    end
end

File.open(file_to_write, "w") do |file|
    file.puts(output_text)
    file.puts(count_of_lines)
end
```

One of the files includes characters that VIM shows as ^Z, which seem to be killing the script before it actually gets to the end of the file.

Is there anything I can do to have Ruby ignore these characters and keep moving through the file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24451098/read-file-ending-early

Comment: Thanks! I used the "rt" flat instead of just "r" based on that thread and it did the trick.

Comment: `/.*\d{3}-\d{7}.*/` can be simplified to `/\d{3}-\d{7}/`. That is, `.*` doesn't make it more restrictive. That matches the string `1234-12345678`, returning `234-1234567`. If you don't want to match that string, you might change the regex to `/\b\d{3}-\d{7}\b/`. `\b` is a "word break". It means that the first matched digit must be at the beginning of the string or preceded by a character other than a digit, letter or underscore. Similar for the last matched digit.

Answer (score 1):

Per Mircea's comment, the answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24451098/read-file-ending-early). I used "rt" based on one of the comments on the selected answer.

Comment: This is not an answer. It should be deleted.